# Protractor: TAB key click is not performed on remote Hub

Tags: protractor, cucumber, selenium-grid, angularjs-e2e

I get the attribute of the active element by clicking TAB key:

```
$('body').sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute("aria-label");
```

When I run the code on the localhost, then the code works correctly. But when I try to run code on the remote hub (selenium grid - AWS server), then the code doesn't work: TAB doesn't make the navigation through the page. The needed element is not an active one.

Comment: you may have to introduce some waits before performing TAB operation

Comment: TAB is part of the Interaction API of a webdriver, can you explain on which browser this fails in combination with which  webdriver (For example Chrome 58 with ChromeDriver 2.29).

Comment: 2 docker containers are used: "selenium/node-chrome:2.53.0" and "selenium/hub:2.53.0"

Comment: As a possible option, may anyone advise how to send TAB key press, using native js in combination with protractor?